# Which Similarity function gives more weight to more common terms?

Tags: search, autocomplete, lucene, elasticsearch, similarity

I'm using Elastic search for auto completer in my website but the problem which I'm facing is, Elastic Search keeps showing me lesser popular searches in the search box on the top. My understanding of Elastic Search says that by default, Elastic Search uses Lucene Scoring formula which is based on tf and idf for score calculation of docs. I think the idf term is giving more weight to rare data items and that is increasing the score of lesser popular searches.

But the similarity module of Elastic Search mentions other similarity functions.
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-similarity.html

Can anyone please tell me which similarity function gives more preference to tf and lesser preference to idf so that I can give more weight to more frequent data items so that common searches can appear on the top in search box ?

I have also read about extending Similarity Class of Lucene and then setting idf to 1 but if there is any other way of achieving the desired result (may be by changing similarity function in mapping) i'll prefer that one.

http://dev.fernandobrito.com/2012/10/building-your-own-lucene-scorer/

Thanks in advance.

tf refers to Term Frequency

idf refers to Inverse Document Frequency

I'm adding some examples for more clarity:

Let's say I have some documents like:

```
> {d:1,text:"delhi to goa"}
> {d:1,text:"delhi to chakan"}
> {d:1,text:"delhi to bak"}
> {d:1,text:"delhi to adf"} 
> {d:1,text:"hangout in delhi"}
> {d:1,text:"hangout in goa"} 
> {d:1,text:"hangout in bareily"}
>  ......
```

And now I search for **delhi to** I'll get following results:

```
delhi to chakan
delhi to bak
delhi to adf
delhi to goa
```

But instead it should give me **delhi to goa** on top.

Similarly, if I search for **hangout in** I'll get following results:

```
hangout in bareily
hangout in goa
hangout in delhi
```

But instead of the above results, I want **hangout in delhi** on top.

I hope the above example make it clear.

Comment: Can you please add some samples of (a) the past searches you are getting and (b) the searches that you want? This smells to me like maybe you need to rethink your search architecture, as usually the rarer terms help narrow the search down to what you want - getting only the common searches seems counter-productive.

Comment: @MarkLeightonFisher: I have updated my question. I hope it makes things somewhat clear now.